# Как определить, целое ли число?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как правильно поставить проверку типа:
Если число res целое то

```
if (...) {
    ...;
}
```

Может есть стандартная ф-я?

Comment: а как число res у Вас объявлено?

Comment: После изменения формулировки вопроса с "Как определить, целое ли число" (это я по памяти) на "Проверка числа на его тип" ответы выглядят **весьма странно**.

--

Уважаемые "редакторы", в подобных случаях потрудитесь обеспечить отсылку на исправляемую версию.

Comment: Уважаемый автор, Вы что Вы имеете в виду:

1) какое значение (целое или с десятичной дробной частью) в переменной типа double или float ?

2) в символьной строке цифры и Вы хотите узнать целое ли число ?

3) "как правильно поставить проверку типа" - это переменная какого типа размещена при компиляции по заданному адресу ?

4) что-то еще ???

Comment: Я не проверял, но возможно if(x%1==0)

Comment: @МаксимШевченко встроенный % работает только с целыми типами в C и C++. Получите ошибку компиляции (на самом деле это забавный способ SFINAE если не пользоваться стандартными трейтами)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давно C++ не использовал, но на сколько я помню такие вещи делаются через оператор привидения типов:

```
dynamic_cast
```

Все другие привидения - это что-то унаследованное от `С`. В `С++` для каждого случая есть свой оператор.

Для проверки встроенных типов данный подход не подойдет. В различных компиляторах есть макросы, например, `__typeof__`. Они специфичны для конкретного компилятора.

`C++` Поддерживает урезанный RTTI. Возможно использовать только языковые возможности `C++`, посмотрите на этот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 10;

    printf("Type is %s", typeid(a).name());
};
```

Comment: Смотрю на описание dynamic_cast - но преобразования простых типов там в упор не вижу....

Answer (score 4):

Или так:

```
if(floor(value) == value)
    ...
```

Для этого надо подключить math.h.

Некоторые могут возразить, что сравнивать числа с плавающей запятой на равенство неправильно. Но если бы это было неправильно всегда, компилятор бы такое в принципе не позволял.
 В данном случае целые числа могут быть представлены точно в double. Операции сложения, вычитания и умножения для целых чисел также дадут целые числа, так как не вносят погрешностей округления. Для чисел, заданных вручную или полученных таким способом, проверка выше сработает корректно.
 Если всё же нужно проверить, что число целое в пределах некоторой погрешности eps (например 0.000001), можно использовать следующую проверку:

```
if(abs(floor(value + 0.5) - value) < eps)
    ...
```

Или если в используемой версии стандартной библиотеки доступна функция round:

```
if(abs(round(value) - value) < eps)
    ...
```

Эти два варианта используют округление к ближайшему целому, чтобы разность между этим и исходным числом была в интервале (-0.5; 0.5], а не [0; 1), как в случае округления к меньшему.

Comment: Вместо floor можно использовать функции ceil или trunc. Ну и надо помнить, что в зависимости от типов параметра/результата у имён этих функций разные суффиксы.

Comment: Теперь есть `round`, `ceil` или `trunc`. Но подключать надо `cmath` а не `math.h`. Не понимаю почему  этот ответ не был принят. Принятый ответ - какой то бред от того, кто не знает языка, его вообще удалить надо.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
float a;

if ( (float)( (int) a ) === a ) //Целое
```

Comment: Что такое ===? Вы C++ с PHP не перепутали случаем?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всегда использовать double (float только для хранения в больших массивах).

```
double r;

if (r == (long long)r) // Целое
```

Comment: на суть подхода это не влияет...

Copy&Paste -  не есть гуд

Comment: Лучше для чего? Они предоставляют большую точность, но при этом занимают больше памяти и в некоторых случаях (например, при расчетах на GPU) скорость операций с double значительно ниже, чем с float.

Comment: To @timka_s, @mikillskegg

"на суть подхода это не влияет..." если это о float и double то в Си очень даже влияет, т.к. при передаче в функции (по default) float преобразуется в double и у новичков иногда возникают "необъяснимые" ошибки.

Лучше сразу привыкнуть применять double (за исключением **особых** случаев (как GPU) и только осознанно использовать float).

Answer (score -1):

```
n = n%2;
if (n == 0) {
    cout << "yep";
}
else {
    cout << "nope";
}
```

Comment: это разве не проверка на чётность?