# поменять цикл while на цикл for. на c++

Tags: c++

***while(**absoluteN>0**)***

***c++***
помогите срочно

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    int N;
    cin >>N;

    if (N%1==0)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int absN=abs(N);

        while (absN>0)
        {
            sum+=absN%10;
            absN/=10;
        }

        cout <<sum;
    }
    else
        {
            cout <<sqrt(abs(N));
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, ничего не понятно по такому обгрызку кода. Во-вторых учебные задачи мы здесь не решаем. Покажите, что сделали вы, и что не получилось.

Comment: на тебе весь код

Comment: #include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    int N;
    cin >>N;

    if (N%10==0)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int absN=abs(N);

        while (absN>0)
        {
            sum+=absN%10;
            absN/=10;
        }

        cout <<sum;
    }
    else
        {
            cout <<sqrt(abs(N));
        }

    return 0;
}

Comment: Если вы хотите что-либо добавить к своему вопросу, не нужно писать это в комментариях. Дополнить вопрос можно нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Давненько не видел такого заминусованного вопроса. Делайте выводы.

Comment: Да це пипець якийсь.

Comment: что по-вашему делает  `N%1` ? Это выражение всегда равно 0...

Comment: А если объявить N как `double` / `float`, то результат `N % 1` нельзя будет использовать для проверки на "целость" числа, так как оператор `%` не определён для чисел с плавающей запятой.  См. [engSO: Testing if given number is integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646512/); [ruSO: Как определить, целое ли число?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/64425/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @NowhereMan в второй ссылке какие-то кривые ответы, особенно принятый ответ (при чем тут вообще dynamic_cast или любое преобразование типов?)

Answer (score 2):

Любая проверка на целое число может столкнуться ситуацией, когда результат ввода целого числа не "помещается" в заложенном типе. Есть значения `int`, которые не помещаются в `double` и если целые значения `double` которые не помещаются в `int`.

В исходном коде вообще запланировано только целое число - `int N`. Самым надежным является проверка на момент ввода.

У потоков есть метод `good()` для проверки состояния. Чтобы прочитать ввод  повторно,можно воспользоваться строковым буфером-потоком `std::stringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int N;
    double R;  

    // сохраним ввод пользователя
    std::stringstream input;
    input << std::cin.rdbuf();

    // считаем как целое. 
    // Дробные числа МОЖНО считать как целое, если они не начинаются с точки.
    input.seekg(0);  
    input >> N;
    bool isInt = input.good();

    // считаем как double
    input.seekg(0);
    input >> R;
    bool isReal = input.good();

    //bool isRound = (isInt && !isReal) ||    // записано как целое
    //           (isReal && (round(R) == R)); // является большим целым в экпс. форме.
    if (isInt && !isReal) {  // если число и не дробное
        int sum = 0;
        for (int absN=abs(N); absN > 0; absN /= 10) {
           sum += absN % 10;
        }
        std::cout <<sum;
    }
    else {
        if(isReal) {
            std::cout << sqrt(abs(round(R)));
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Ошибка ввода";
        }
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Конечно же, запись вроде 3.14e+12 описывает ЦЕЛОЕ число 3140000000000, которое не поместится в `int`, но, похоже, условия задачи такой вариант не рассматривают. Можно также исключить возможность ввода экспоненты.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (; absN > 0; absN /= 10) {
    sum += absN % 10;
}
```

Comment: код опять не работает так как надо

Comment: Что у тебя конкретно не работает ?

Comment: Якщо задане число ціле, то вам необхідно вивести суму цифр цього числа, інакше вивести
корінь квадратний із модуля цього числа.

Comment: код должен ето виполнять

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    if (N % 1 == 0) {
        int sum = 0;
        int absN = abs(N);

        // Заменяем цикл while на цикл for
        for (; absN > 0; absN /= 10) {
            sum += absN % 10;
        }

        cout << sum;
    } else {
        cout << sqrt(abs(N));
    }

    return 0;
}

Comment: @СашаНавроцький `int N;` - всегда целое.  требования к выводу нужно приводить, это часть минимального примера

Comment: Спасибо за помощь